# cookie filename and location in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

Im new to JSP and trying to set a cookie in my jsp file,

Here are my files

get_Request.jsp

```
<%
    Cookie firstname = new Cookie("first_name",request.getParameter("first_name"));
    Cookie lastname = new Cookie("last_name",request.getParameter("last_name"));
    firstname.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
    lastname.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
    response.addCookie(firstname);
    response.addCookie(lastname);

%>

<html>
<head>
<title>
Using get method to read form data
</title>
<ul>
    <li><p><b>First Name:</b>
    <%= request.getParameter("first_name")%>
    </p></li>
    <li><p><B>Last Name:</b>
    <b><%= request.getParameter("last_name")%></b>
    </p></li>
</ul>
</head>
</html>
```

hello.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="get_request.jsp"method="GET">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I have set the cookie but I'm not sure what would be my filename and location of the cookie?

Comment: Why do you need to know the file name and location of the cookie? You can retrieve the cookie like this: Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies(); This returns an array of cookie objects.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question..

Comment: Would you elaborate a little more regarding the need to know the filename and location of the cookie. Cookies are stored on the client in a browser specific location. You don't have access to this location. The only access you have to the cookie you set is via the getCookie() method which retrieves all the cookies that you set.

Comment: Im running a Apache tomcat in my machine..and testing the code in my machine..I'm trying to identify where and how the cookies are stored.

Comment: Obviously that depends on your browser. In Firefox they won't be in the same place as in IE. Cookie location on the client has nothing to do with the serverside code; it has to do with the browser.